# Browser appending web address to local file path

Tags: php, html

I have an admin website trying to fetch images from a publc site on the same server but for some reason the path to the image file is being modified by my browser:

admin site: `www/admin/`

public sit: `www/public/`

Here is my php code from the admin site:

```
$imgPATH = "/var/www/public/assets/images/".$valuesArray["brand"]."/".$imgID."/";

foreach (glob ($imgPATH."*.*") as $file) {
   $imgListing .= "<img src='".$file."'><br>";
};
```

this code gives me the correct path in my HTML `<img src="/var/www/public/etc...">` but for some reason safari is appending the admin site web address and giving me this error in the console:

`[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (image.png, line 0)`

the error gives the following address: `https://www.adminsite.com/var/www/public/assets/images/etc..`

I also tried `../` instead of beginning with `/` with same error
but it used to work fine with another folder (same permissions)...

Comment: That is not an error, that is how resolving relative URLs to absolute ones _works_. The problem is that you are outputting _file system_ paths in a place where you should put URLs instead. _“this code gives me the correct path in my HTML”_ -  no, it doesn’t. It _looks_ “correct” to you, because you are not aware of the aforementioned difference.

Comment: `public site: www/public/` - so is there a separate domain pointing to this - analog to `www.adminsite.com`, this would be `www.publicsite.com` then? And your actual images are available via a path like `https://www.publicsite.com/assets/images/...`? Then that’s the path you should output as the `src` attribute content for your image elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLs starting with a single `/` are *relative* URLs with absolute paths. They are computed relative to the URL of the current document.

If you want to generate an HTTP URL on your server, then you'll need to do so starting at the DocumentRoot of your HTTP server and not from the root of your file system.

If you want to generate a URL directly to your file system, then you'll need an absolute URL that begins the URL scheme (`file:`)… but this will only work if the server and browser are running on the same computer, and will run into security restrictions that apply when moving from HTTP to local files.

Comment: I tried `../var/www/public/etc...` but I get the same error; what do you mean by `URL scheme (file:)` please ?

Comment: I'm not surprised. Try doing what I suggested in this answer instead.

Comment: thanks I guess that fixed the 404; now Im getting `Not allowed to load local resource` hummm permissions...

Comment: "Not allowed to load local resource" suggests that you hit the "security restrictions that apply when moving from HTTP to local files".

Comment: if you are interested I could not use `file://` in the end because of browser security restriction disallowing loading local files but I managed to get around that by creating a symlink so I could use a regular file path.